# QtWebKit or Server side? Can't translate xml: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: XSLTProcessor

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtwebkit

I need to open a webpage inside a QWebView in my Qt Widgets Application.

The web works fine, except one part, where some files are not downloading from the server.

I inspected the QWebView and I found that error in the title...
It seems weird, because I tried to compile my app in linux with same Qt version and it works fine, no error in Web Inspector console... I tried compiling with MinGW32 and also with MSVC 2013 with same results.

I tried the same webpage with Qupzilla WebBrowser and it works!!, even in Windows (so I am afraid that is Qt setting in my app, that is only needed in Windows environment, but I couldn't find for it in the QupZilla sources...)

**Error detail in windows:**
[image: Detail]

(In linux the same action produces no error)

**Top: Linux build, processed 45 requests, Windows build(bottom) stopped at 15 requests..., same code:**
[image: Requests]

Another things I tried:
- Changing user agent
- Playing with QWebSettings
- And maybe another unuseful tries.

Any clue to get my page fully loaded into the Windows QWebView?

Comment: I solved it temporarily by using a QWebEngineView to render the page, but I don't like that solution because it force me to compile with MSVC and probably I will have problems when I want to go multplatform... So any workarrounds will be welcome

Comment: You should definitely consider using WebEngine since QtWebKit is a deprecated module.